# Anthropologist and blind passenger investigate ancient temple on first manned expedition to alien planet

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read a sci-fi book about 4-6 years back, when I was about 15, and I'd like to reread it, but it was from the library and I can't remember the author or title, only pretty vague pieces of the plot.

It's about an anthropologist (m (?)) who's on an early expedition on a foreign planet (outside our solar system, one of the first human manned expeditions on this planet) and a blind passenger (f) who came with his ship, and they're investigating what seems to be a temple of an ancient civilization; the rest of the expedition dies pretty early.

The temple consists of a spiral (?) corridor that's full of traps, and seems to have been built for beings much bigger than humans.

I'm not sure what's at the center, except that the MCs become friends over the course of the book.

The planet is dominated by a blue-white desert (I think); the MCs are far younger than you'd expect on a mission like this nowadays (<18 years old I think).

Today I'd call this book very short, about the size of Alloy of Law probably.

PS: The book is *not* Hyperion by Dan Simmons.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Nicely detailed question.  Do you remember any details about the cover of the book?  Did this ship have a large crew, or was it just a team of scientists?

Comment: For those who don't want to look it up, *Alloy of Law* is around 330 pages for most English-language HC and TP editions.

Comment: Thanks! Sadly, I don't remember much else about the book. The ship's crew isn't very big, and I think the male MC is one of very few (if not the only) scientists on board.